# INSERT fail after set DEFAULT value column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-insert

I add column to table as:

```
RedMarkItemsId (IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
TaskId (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
CreationDate (DATETIME)
CreatedBy (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

I want to create column like:

```
  ALTER TABLE RedMarkItems ADD Item1 BIT DEFAULT(0)
```

But when I try to insert some values:

```
INSERT INTO RedMarkItems 
VALUES (
    '9B093907-2072-4F59-A55C-0003CE89EF9E', 
    GETDATE(), 
    '6074CAEA-7A8E-4699-9451-16C2EAF394EF')
```

It throws error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Why I'm getting this error if I set `DEFAULT(0)` to that new column?

Table create script:

```
CREATE TABLE RedMarkItems 
(
    RedMarkItemsId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TaskId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    CreationDate DATETIME,
    CreatedBy UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)
```

Comment: In my insert statement I have TaskId, CreationDate and CreatedBy, I don't need to specify RedMarkItemsId because it's an IDENTITY(1,1), so it's autonumeric field @gtosto

Comment: Think about it a bit more: that `identity` could instead be anywhere positionally in the list of columns, so SQL Server can't guess that the 3 values you supplied are supposed to go into the 3 columns you named; you have to tell it. This is a good thing: the language is being consistent, rather than being overly charitable by making an assumption if the `identity` happens to be the 1st column, where that assumption could lead to unexpected results and would only work in 1 situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This piece of SQL is not valid :

```
INSERT INTO RedMarkItems 
VALUES (
    '9B093907-2072-4F59-A55C-0003CE89EF9E', 
    GETDATE(), 
    '6074CAEA-7A8E-4699-9451-16C2EAF394EF')
```

When not providing all columns for insert, you need to explicitly specify the target columns. As you are assigning only 3 columns, you probably want :

```
INSERT INTO RedMarkItems(
    RedMarkItemsId, 
    TaskId, 
    CreationDate
) VALUES (
    '9B093907-2072-4F59-A55C-0003CE89EF9E', 
    GETDATE(), 
    '6074CAEA-7A8E-4699-9451-16C2EAF394EF'
);
```

Comment: It seems, RedMarkItemsId should be replaced with TaskId. He wants to omit the RedMarkItemsId as it is an Identity column...